# C++ Boost not found file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, visual-studio-2015, c++03

I'm trying to use `variant` from boost and I'm receiving this error:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/variant.hpp': No
>   such file or directory

I've included the files in project properties.

[image]

In the **Reference Directories** and **Library Directories** I've tried also with

- "...\lib"
- "....\stage\lib"

And also in the **Include Directories** I've tried also with:

- "...\boost_1_68_0"
- "...\boost_1_68_0\boost"

In the beginning, I used ***D:\Libs\boost_1_68_0\libs*** and because it didn't work I've compiled boost and I've tried with ***D:\Libs\boost_1_68_0\stage\lib*** after that.

But it didn't work out.

Also, I should say that I've tried this in VisualStudio2010 and also in 2015 and I've followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AmwIwedTCM).

Any solution for me? Thanks in advice :)

Comment: It's the *header file* directory that can't be found, i.e. the `Include Directories` part. Does `D:\Libs\boost_1_68_0\boost` contain a directory `boost` with a file `variant.hpp`? My ***guess*** is that it should be `D:\Libs\boost_1_68_0\boost\include` or similar. Go to the directory and find the files to find out.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've forgot to mention that, I just edit my question.

Comment: and I don't have such kind of folder in boost, so is not like that...

Comment: It is not like that but how it **is**? You fail to mention where **is** "boost" directory with file "variant.hpp" in it on your hard drives.

Comment: @ÖöTiib if you want to know the specific location is here "D:\Libs\boost_1_68_0\boost"

Comment: So there is another directory "boost" in that "D:\Libs\boost_1_68_0\boost" and it contains "variant.hpp"?

Comment: Do you have `D:\Libs\boost_1_68_0\boost\boost\variant.hpp`? If not then you need to search for `variant.hpp` to figure out where it is. Note that you will probably get multiple hits.

Comment: Yes I do have on **D:\Libs\boost_1_68_0\boost\variant.hpp**

Comment: So if you want to include `boost/variant.hpp` what directory should you set?

Answer (score 0):

You have set your include to `D:\Libs\boost_1_68_0\boost`. But the includes in your code will look like `<boost/variant.hpp>`. So if you set your include, instead, to `D:\Libs\boost_1_68_0` then the `<boost/whatever/...>` will follow from there.

What you really should do is set an environment variable called `BOOST_ROOT` to `D:\Libs\boost_1_68_0`. Then in your project set additional includes with `$(BOOST_ROOT)` Note that you have to restart Visual Studio for the environment change to take effect.

Now in the future, when boost_1_69 comes out, you can put it where ever you would like and all the previous projects where you have used `$(BOOST_ROOT)` will follow when you up date the environment variable.

Always build your boost lib in `/stage/lib`, it is the default for the `b2` builder. And for your additional libs use `$(BOOST_ROOT)/stage/lib`